# Как загрузить картинку из памяти телефона при нажатии на кнопку загрузки, которая находится в webview?

Tags: android, webview

В приложении есть WebView. Внутри этого WebView есть кнопка "Загрузить файл". При нажатии на эту кнопку ничего не происходит. Как загрузить картинку из памяти телефона?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [следующим примером](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42266387/5330439)

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/image_name.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body> <img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"> </body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

Comment: TimurVI, я имела ввиду что пользователь может выбрать любое изображение со своего телефона

Comment: Год назад где то на такую загрузку был запрет.